# Putting a check on the values returned from a query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query which returns a few rows. I need to check if the values in all of the returned rows is more than 0.

Example:
**query** :select qty-balance from tbl_orders;
**result:**
qty
1.00000000
1.00000000
1.00000000
1.00000000
1.00000000
1.00000000

I have to check that none of the returned rows have a value  less than 0; Like a if condition

Comment: What have you tried so far? And where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: What is your query? What values are being returned? If you are just wanting to filter out anything that does not have a value greater than one, you should be able to add a `WHERE value > 0` or, if you have aggregate functions in the query, `HAVING value > 0`

Comment: I have no idea of putting checks on the result set returned by queries. I could not find anything online as well.

Comment: I have to make sure that all of the results rows returned have a value that is greater than 0.  the query returns the difference between the values of two columns. I have to make sure that all of the rows returned have values greater than 1

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result  ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select
    qty
from
    tbl_orders
where
    qty >= 0.0;
```

Comment: The query is actually a difference of two column values.I need to put an if condition on the result set. If even one of the rows has a values greaterthan zero than I need to go to else.